# Mongoaudit problems to install

Tags: python, mongodb, curl

I want to install and use Mongoaudit but have some problems to use it.At first, I tried to install it using PIP but have tabulation problems with the file main.py. When i solve it, the file didn´t find the imports when it´s all at the same folder and correct.  Later I try to install it using curl but don´t find the file or directory to download and install it.

This is the official mongoaudit page: http://mongoaud.it/ and I get the curl command from this page but don´t work.

I´m using windows 10 and python 3.6

Thanks you

Comment: did you try to follow : https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/, or https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Mongo-Database-setup-on-6963f46f ... ?

Comment: I´m using mongodb since 3 months ago. The problems is mongoaudit that is a tool for auditing MongoDB servers

Comment: ho ok... I didn't know that... sorry I can't help...